# How to Implement panning like functionality (right to left or left to right )to switch between textviews

Tags: android

I want to implement next previous functionality in my EBook application.This should be done on data.When I move(with onTouch) my finger right to left (or left to right) on screen then next chapter data appear like image gallery. in  image gallery when we switch between images by onTouch ,if we move one image right to left then next image appears and previous image disappears as next appears.like panning.But I want to implement this functionality using text views. and i want to switch between text views like this pattern....

please guide and help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch views with animation you can use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with your custom animation. You can find many examples which describe way to using ViewFlipper, one of them - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/ViewFlipper_Animation.aspx

Comment: thanks Grigory Kalabin.. One thing need more clarification. i am using one textview to show data on screen.. so i need to reload/update data on that textview. so it is one view that reappear again and again..so when i move one view(chapter data) to next.. it works but like one view not two as image gallery (two images show at the same time on screen)..i think i would use two textviews to gain the proper functionality. as if one move data load on 2nd textview etc.... m i right..??

Comment: you can use some textview from your layout but not from flipper and update it right after or before flipper.showNext/Prev call